# Discrete maths; graph theory on undirected graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let G be an undirected graph of 4 vertices and no loops (i.e. arrows to itself). Which of the following statements are guaranteed to be true?

1) G has at least two vertices of the same degree

2) G has a Hamilton-path

3) Between to distinct vertices there is a simple path

4) G has a Euler-path

The answer is apparently 3), and not 1). I can not for the life of me draw a graph without at least two vertices of the same degree that is undirected with 4 vertices and no loops.

The exact terminology might have been lost as I translated it from norwegian.

Cheers.

Comment: You're correct, it should be 1. Number 3 is untrue, you can just take any unconnected graph on 4 vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can prove (1) by the pigeonhole principle.  The possible degrees of each vertex are 0,1,2,3.  If two are the same, we are done.  If not, there is one of each degree; however the vertex of degree 3 must have an edge to each other, including the vertex of degree 0.  This is a contradiction.